# Channel Entries - addon to charge members per entry?

Tags: channel-entries, add-on, add-on-development, entries, addons

Does EE have an addon, either native or third party, that can charge members to post entries? Some entries will be a one time payment while others need to be recurring. I need the entry to expire at a certain date, or if a future payment fails, etc. Email notifications to keep members aware of payments, etc. would be useful.

I know this sounds very specific, but I'm hoping something already exist than having to build something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer : I'm the developer of [Charge](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/charge) so am biased on this.

**Yes** - this is all quite simple with [Charge](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/charge). You'd simply use the standard front-end entry form as usual and set the entry status to a pending state, then use the built in [entry actions](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/charge/docs/actions) in Charge to update the status to live after a successful payment.

This can all be used with recurring payments, and if you need to later down grade or alter the status of the entry you can use the [provided hooks](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/charge/docs/hooks) to trigger any extra logic you might want.

To be fair - this same setup is likely possible using other third party addons but I can't speak for the exact setup on those.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a store add-on as a workaround.

I'm using Expresso Store. You could add a custom text field to a product and use it to store the id of an channel form entry.

This might also be possible using other add-on, such as Simple Commerce or CartThrob.

Comment: Also check out Charge: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/charge

Comment: Added my response about Charge above http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/30357/1111

Answer (score 0):

I've reached similar functionality some time ago using Membrr. DevDemon Subscriptions might also work for this.